# Cloud SQL Console SQL Prompt -> Only returns a single column

Tags: jquery, sql, database, google-cloud-sql

If I execute queries in the google cloud console, I always get back a single column. See the first screenshot. My table actually contains lots of columns and a `select * from article` should return all of the columns.

If I specify a specific column like `select text from article`, I get that column (See second screenshot). If I select multiple columns separated with comma (`select id, test from article`), I get the first specified column.

What is going wrong here? Is that some kind of bug in the console? I think this worked at some point. Or is there any setting I could change?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After creating a new SQL instance, it is working again.